How to copy all methods from one class to another using Gizmo in Quarkus?
I currently have an interface。that looks like this
public interface JRepository<E, ID> {

    // sqlClient
    JSqlClient sql();

    // crud methods
    E findNullable(ID id);

    List<E> findByIds(Iterable<ID> ids);
}

This interface has an implementation class that looks like this
public class JRepositoryImpl<E, ID> implements JRepository<E, ID> {
    @Override
    public JSqlClient sql() {
        return just return sqlClient;
    }

    @Override
    public E findNullable(ID id) {
        // Some logic
        return sql().findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> findByIds(Iterable<ID> ids) {
        // Some logic
        return sql().findByIds(ids);
    }
}

Users can choose to extend the interface to get CRUD methods that looks like this
public interface TestRepository extends JRepository<Book, Long> {
}

Now I want to implement the interface for the user-defined TestRepository through the default implementation class JRepositoryImpl.
I encountered some issues with Quarkus’s Gizmo. It seems that Gizmo is unable to copy the method bodies from the methods.
It seems that when I use methods like ClassCreator and MethodCreator, there are no APIs available to copy the method bodies.
If I want to achieve my goal, do I have to use the lower-level ClassVisitor and MethodVisitor, or is there a better way? Are there any similar codes that I can reference?
I’m currently encountering some issues while generating the code using bytecode.
@ApplicationScoped
@Unremovable
public class TestRepository_edb259d1f267785b946cb0bcfd7d69d6e7653180Impl implements TestRepository {
    private final TestInterface defaultImpl;

    public TestRepository_edb259d1f267785b946cb0bcfd7d69d6e7653180Impl() {
    }

    public TestRepository_edb259d1f267785b946cb0bcfd7d69d6e7653180Impl(JSqlClient var1) {
        ClassLoader var2 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Class var3 = Class.forName("com.Book", false, var2);
        TestInterfaceImpl var4 = new TestInterfaceImpl(var1, var3);
        this.defaultImpl = (TestInterface)var4;
    }

    public Object findNullable(Object var1) {
        return this.defaultImpl.findNullable(var1);
    }

    public Class entityType() {
        return this.defaultImpl.entityType();
    }

    public JSqlClient sql() {
        return this.defaultImpl.sql();
    }
}

When I inject it, Quarkus throws the following error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "TestInterface.findNullable(Object)" because "this.defaultImpl" is null.
public class TestInterfaceImpl<E, ID> implements TestInterface<E, ID> {

    protected final JSqlClientImplementor sqlClient;

    protected final Class<E> entityType;

    protected TestInterfaceImpl(JSqlClient sqlClient) {
        this(sqlClient, null);
    }

    public TestInterfaceImpl(JSqlClient sqlClient, Class<E> entityType) {
        this.sqlClient = Utils.validateSqlClient(sqlClient);
        this.entityType = entityType;
    }

    @Override
    public JSqlClient sql() {
        return sqlClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<E> entityType() {
        return entityType;
    }

    @Override
    public E findNullable(ID id) {
        return sqlClient.getEntities().findById(entityType, id);
    }
}


If you know that a default implementation exists and can obtain an instance in the constructor (glossing over how exactly you do that), you don't have to copy the method bodies -- you can just forward to them. That should be fairly simple. If you have a Jandex ClassInfo for the interface (iface), you can do just:

for (MethodInfo method : iface.methods()) {
    MethodCreator m = clazz.getMethodCreator(method);
    ResultHandle delegate = m.readInstanceField(m.getThis(), ...);
    ResultHandle [] args = new ResultHandle[method.parametersCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < method.parametersCount(); i++) {
        args[i] = m.getParam(i);
    }
    m.returnValue(m.invokeInterface(method, delegate, args));
}

Note that I'm writing this from memory on my phone, so there might be typos, but the structure should be obvious.

Thank you for you help. However, I encountered some issues when generating the constructor code. Could you please help guide me through it? I’ve included the code in this question.

I'm sorry, I don't understand what TestInterface and TestInterfaceImpl are. My understanding was that you would create an instance of JRepositoryImpl in the constructor, store it in the field, and then forward to that.

Yes, TestInterfaceImpl is the instance I am going to create, which is what you understand as JRepositoryImpl. It’s named this way because it’s for testing purposes. However, in the generated code, I clearly instantiated this object, but the final result says that this object doesn’t exist:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke “TestInterface.findNullable(Object)” because “this.defaultImpl” is null.

If this is in a @QuarkusTest, there might be an issue in how JUnit instantiates the test class and then Quarkus instantiates the test class for the second time, trying to "copy" over everything from the first instance -- but that's just a wild speculation. I see there's an empty constructor -- how do you create an instance of TestRepository_edb259d1f267785b946cb0bcfd7d69d6e7653180Impl?

It seems that my Arc container has not been fully initialized, and the sqlClient I injected will only be available after the Arc container is fully initialized. The question now is, is there any way to make the build item run after the Arc container is completed?

The class that needs to be instantiated has already been added to the question.
